# Not able to run Dtale on root url

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, google-cloud-talent-solution

We have a requirement to run the multiple Dtale serives in one docker container. So we are planning to run each dtale service with a unique app-root and port. Below is my code looks like.

```
import dtale
d = dtale.show(pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5]),host='localhost',app_root="/satya",port="40000")
d._main_url

d1 = dtale.show(pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5]),host='localhost',app_root="/test",port="40001")
d1._main_url
```

Below is the error we are getting when accessing the dtale url.

[image]

I am expecting two dtale services running on

1. localhost:40000/satya/main/1
2. localhost:40001/test/main/1